# How to extend built-in slot type with additional values in Alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Actually, I have used AMAZON.DATE which is Alexa built-in slot. Now I want to add 'daily' value in that slot. So can anyone tell me how to extend Alexa built-in slots, like how to add additional values in the built-in slot? Please give an example.

You can see I have user AMAZON.DATE in my set reminder intent in image 1
[image]

In image 2 you can see built-in slot type but I do not get any option to add any additional values. So please help me to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#extend-a-slot-type) you can extend a built-in slot type:

> Before you can extend a built-in type, you need to add it to your skill. In the left-hand navigation, note the types under Slot Types. If the slot type to extend is not included, add it to your skill:
>
> 1. From the left-hand navigation, click Add next to Slot Types.
> 2. Select the Use an existing slot type from Alexa's built-in library option.
> 3. Find the built-in slot type you want to add. You can filter the slot types by name.
> 4. Click Add Slot Type for each built-in type to add.
> 5. Be sure to save your work as you make changes.
>
> To extend a built-in slot type, add values to it just as you would a custom type. In the left-hand navigation, under Slot Types, select the slot type to edit. Enter each value and click the plus or press Enter.
>
> For more about creating and editing slot types in the developer console, see Create and Edit Custom Slot Types

But it looks, that you cannot extend `AMAZON.DATE` slot (since it's not a list slot type - more details [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#slot-types-you-can-extend))

So in order to handle `daily` word, you should create a separate custom slot called for example `FrequencySlot`, and define there some values (see attachment) and then - add new utterances to your intent and handle new slot type in the code.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @slawciu. This explanation is very helpful to me.