# Is there a way to handle 29th February in AMAZON.DATE?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

While evaluating a model it shows output as below screenshot and there is no check for Leap Year. And when I test the skill it goes to FallBack Intent. And another thing I learned from [How to extend built-in slot type with additional values in Alexa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022398/how-to-extend-built-in-slot-type-with-additional-values-in-alexa) we cannot edit AMAZON.DATE(I cannot add 29th Feb to slot values also).

How can we resolve this?[image]

Comment: You mean that the utterance profiler resolves to the value shown while the running skill goes to fallback intent when you say 29th february?

Comment: Yes Exactly. @German

Comment: There might be a difference between you typing it and you saying it. Please check on the the simulator and instead of typing 29th February just say it by pressing the mic. Then please tell me if it's capturing the date correctly. If it is then this is a bug that has to be reported